# bass.dll корректное отображение тэгов интернетрадио

Tags: c#, кодировка, bass.dll, bass.net

Здравствуйте,
пишу на c# программу — интернет-радио, используя библиотеку *bass.dll*. Название песни, исполнителя и т.д. получаю следующим образом:

```cs
TAG_INFO tagInfo = new TAG_INFO(url);
_stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateURL(url, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT, null, IntPtr.Zero);

if (BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromURL(_stream, tagInfo))
{
    album = tagInfo.album.ToString();
    artist = tagInfo.artist.ToString();
}
```

Когда тэги на английском, т.е. латиницей, то проблем нет — все отображается нормально, но если на русском, то появляются кракозябры. Причем язык операционной системы не всегда играет роль.

Если возможность как-то скорректировать кодировку, чтобы *bass.dll* правильно отображал тэги?

Comment: Это вопрос не к нам, а к разработчикам библиотеки. Откуда мы знаем, какой у них там баг?

Answer (score 2):

Теги могут храниться как в однобайтовой кодировке, так и в различных юникодовых кодировках. Если аудио-файлы старые или созданы неправильной программой, то библиотека может быть бессильна и просто делать единственное возможное в данной ситуации — подбирать кодировку на авось. Соответственно, результат может зависеть от конкретной реализации авося: то ли это будет кодировка, основанная на текущей локали юзера, то ли кодировка для неюникодовых приложений, то ли просто фиксированная кодировка, которая нравится автору библиотеки.

Если хотите более полезный ответ, то приведите пример ваших кракозябров в разных случаях. По их внешнему виду можно будет понять: то ли библиотека использует не ту кодировку, то ли не умеет кодировки, то ли не умеет юникод.

Comment: Прежде чем задать вопрос здесь, я, конечно, задал его на un4seen.com, но ответа пока не получил.
примероы:
Ì\Ô ÙÅËÊÓÍ×ÈÊ

0000 UK 0000 Ñ€ÐµÐºÐ»Ð°Ð¼Ð° 10

BabayBox (101.ru) и Юникид (Новоссибирск). Немецкая операционная система, хотя, что касается Юникид, то и на русской системе таже проблема.

Мне не обязательно для прочтения тэгов использовать возможности bass, но например, при помощи HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse у меня не получается получить всю ту информацию, что выдает bass. Для этого я использовал пример http://www.codeproject.com/vb/net/SHOUTcastSave.asp

Comment: "Ñ€ÐµÐºÐ»Ð°Ð¼Ð°" — это Юникод в кодировке UTF8, прочитанный как Windows-1252. Это плохой признак: скорее всего, проблема не в файле, а в библиотеке. "Ì\Ô ÙÅËÊÓÍ×ÈÊ" уже попахивает неверной кодировкой, но неооружённым взглядом что-то не признаю. Не могу посоветовать ничего дельного, кроме как попробовать другие библиотеки, желательно специализирующиеся на тегах, а не воспроизведении. Теги для BASS — это второстепенная функция.

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению, подходящей библиотеки не нахожу. почему-то они не читают тэги с интернетрадио-потока. как например, taglib-sharp. Может Вы знаете подходящую?

Comment: @Владимир Нет, не знаю. Если ищете только библиотеки для .NET, то попробуйте вообще любые (обычно C/C++).

Comment: спасибо. буду искать.